# Quick Build In Android with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-build

I have a android project which is huge in size with more than 100 resource files, layouts and lot of codes. It takes about a minute and even more to completely build. Even when I change a single line or just give a space the whole project takes 1 minute to build. But I want it to consider only the changes and build quickly when there is very less change. Is there a way to do it. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as I know partial builds are not possible. You can disable the "Build Automatically" (not 100% sure about the name, I don't have Eclipse open right now) option from Eclipse and start the build manually.

Answer (score 0):

Could you comment out or just run the classes that have changed by themselves? I guess maybe this is one of the reasons they push encapsulation so much with object oriented programming.